# How is the capacitance of a capacitor defined?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, voltage, capacitance, definition

We know that capacitance of a conductor is the ratio of charge stored in it to the potential at the surface of the conductor, $C=q/V$. But how is capacitance of a capacitor consisting of $2$ conductors defined ($\mathrm{C = q/(p.d)}$ between conductors). I want to see the derivation involved that led to this conclusion.

Comment: Isn't this just a definition?

Comment: The formula for capacitance of an isolated conductor was derived from the fact that Potential of a conductor is related to the excess charge on it. On what basis is the capacitance of the capacitor defined?

Comment: It is defined by $Q/V$, as you said.

Comment: But here V is the potential at the surface of one conductor. In the formula for capacitance of a capacitor, V is the potential difference between the two conductors.

Comment: No. There is no such thing as a potential for a single  conductor. It is always a potential *difference*. In the "isolated" condctor case the other potential is that at infinity.

Comment: I agree. But potential at a surface can be estimated to be the work done by electric field in moving a unit test positive charge from a point in it's vicinity to a point where it's influence can't be felt by the charge

Comment: The $V$ in the capacitance definition is the potential difference between the two conductors. I.e the work to move a unit charge from one to the other.

Comment: @mikestone "There is no such thing as a potential for a single conductor. " That is not correct. For example, the potential of a spherical conductor of radius $r$ with charge $q$ is $\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r}$.

Comment: @my2cts If I define the potential to be zero at the coordinate origin, then the potential of a spherical conductor of radius $r$ with charge  $q$ is zero.

Comment: @J. Murray You are touching on the issue of gauge invariance. To a gauge theorist the potential at the surface of a charged sphere of radius r is $V=-\frac{q}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r}$ plus the four gradient of a _completely arbitrary_ scalar field. I prove here that that is an unneccessary obfuscation: https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0106078 .

Comment: @my2cts That's an interesting paper, but you are still imposing a boundary condition at spatial infinity, which is my point.  Constant shifts in potential are invisible both to the standard formulation of EM and the one you present, which means the actual value of the potential is not physical.  The potential *relative to a prescribed reference point* is physical, but e.g. when I'm working in my lab, I measure potential relative to the big metal table my equipment sits on, not spatial infinity.

Comment: @J.Murray You have to be pragmatic when working with capacitors, sure, and this point takes us quite far from that practice. Fundamental theory, however, should be fussy about such details in my opinion. Nevertheless, the theory in my paper does _not_ allow addition of an arbitrary constant to for example the potential of a charged sphere. Such a constant changes the total energy of a EM interacting system by an arbitrary amount and for example, the total energy must be positive. In gauge invariant QM you can, because you alter the wave function to compensate for this arbitrary change.

Answer (score 1):

What matters with a capacitor is the *potential difference V* between the two conductors. The capacitance is then defined as before, as *C* = *Q*/*V*.

One can think of a single conductor as having a potential and capacitance relative to some reference or ambient potential of 0V, i.e. we take the potential difference between 0V and the conductor. If you change your reference potential then the apparent capacitance will also change.

Comment: However the total charge on the capacitor is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Consider qa capacitor made up of two parallel plates of surface $A$ and distance $d$, separated by a medium with relative dielectric constant $\epsilon_r$. The field of each plate will be $$E = \frac{Q}{2 \epsilon_0 \epsilon A}$$, neglecting edge effects. Between the plates the fields add up to $$E = \frac{Q}{\epsilon_0 \epsilon_r A}$$ and outside the plates they cancel. The potential difference is $$V=Ed=\frac{Qd}{\epsilon_0 \epsilon_r A}$$ so the capacity is $$C = \frac{\epsilon_0 \epsilon_r A}{d} ~.$$

Answer (score 0):

Capacitance, in terms of its physical features, is given by

$$C=\frac{εA}{d}$$

Where $A$ = plate area, $ε$ = electrical permittivity of the space between the plates and $d$ = distance between plates.

The potential difference $V$ between the plates of the capacitor is

$$V=Ed$$

Where $E$ is the uniform electric field between the plates. Or

$$d=\frac{V}{E}$$

Substituting into the first equation

$$C=\frac{εAE}{V}$$

The electric field between infinite parallel plates (or plates with dimensions much greater than there separation $d$) is

$$E=\frac{ρ_{s}}{ε}=\frac{q}{εA}$$

Substituting into the previous equation

$$C=\frac{q}{V}$$

Hope this helps.